# How to add a class to the last elements of a row

Tags: jquery, row, addclass

I have a dynamically generated list. I divided the layout as follows:
each line has three elements and in the third element (the last of the line) a class is added to change the style using jQuery, with the following code:

**$(".produto_individual").map(function(i, e){ if(((i+1) % 3) == 0)return e;}).addClass('last');**

What I wanted to do is the following, pick the last elements of the list and add a class too. However, the number of elements varies, so the number of elements of the last row can be 1, 2 or 3 then the list can have the following formats.:

```
x x x
x x x
x x x
x
```

OR

```
x x x
x x x
x x x
x x
```

OR

```
x x x
x x x
x x x
x x x
```

In any case my desire is to select the elements of the last row (which are dynamically generated) and add a class to them. But I have no idea where to start.

The HTML e PHP:

`idcategorias,$categoria->idcategorias) as $item):

```
   $fotos = Modulo::Fotos('',$item->idprodutos,5);
   $fotos = $fotos[0];
   ?>
   <a href="produtos/<?php echo $categoria->url?>/<?php echo $item->url_sub?>/<?php echo $item->url?>/">
        <div class="produto_individual">
            <center><img src="imagens/produtos/pequena/<?php echo $fotos->caminho?>" alt="" width="161" height="135" /></center>
            <h1><?php echo $item->nome?></h1>
        </div></a>
      <?php endforeach?>`
```

THIS IS NOT A TABLE.

Comment: can you show the relevant html..?

Answer (score 0):

> my desire is to select the elements of the last row (which are
>   dynamically generated) and add a class to them.

Assuming you want to added `class` to elements having class `produto_individual` and are in last `row`.

```
$("yourTableId tr:last .produto_individual").addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 0):

add class to last row

```
$('#tableID tr:last').addClass('last');
```

Add class to every row last column in

```
$('#tableID tr').find('td:last').addClass('last');
```

add class to last row last td

```
$('#tableID tr:last td:last').addClass('last');
```